# Full Calendar weekly Mode

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, timetable

I am trying to build an application that displays a weekly Monday to Friday school schedule. I've decided to use the JQuery plugin fullcalendar. After looking through many options, I cannot find a way to display a weekly mode rather than actual days of the year. Agenda mode displays a given week of the year. This includes dates which I don't want.

I want events to begin on Friday at 2:00pm not April 5 at 2:00pm

Is there way to do this using the fullcalendar API?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at  the `columnFormat` option. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/columnFormat/

```
columnFormat: {
    month: 'ddd',
    week: 'ddd',
    day: 'dddd M/d'
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That works for hiding the dates, but I'm still having trouble with adding events. I finally managed to add an event to a specific day such as "April 1 2013 at 14:00 until April 1 2013 at 16:30."

Is there a way to simply add an event to Mondays instead of attaching an event to April 1 2013?

Comment: The API by default doesn't provide any way to add events to all Mondays. What you can do however is disable the next/prev buttons and render the timetable without any date information. That way your timetable will be fully generic.

Comment: By default the calendar will show events for "April 1 - April 5" Anyone who uses the app next week will see events for "April 8 - April 12" is there a way to set the dates upon initialization? And is it cheating to permanently initialize the week to April 1 - April 5 and map all Monday events to April 1 2013, all Tuesday events to April 2 2013...

Comment: Yes, you can use the `gotoDate` function right after init (or on the `viewDisplay` callback) - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/.
Also, I don't think it's cheating if you use the tools the way you want them. And if you think FC is too much trouble, check this option - http://static.triballabs.net/Bootstrap/Timetable.htm